# Starting multithread python code from c++

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, mfc

I'd like to create a simple python webserver to expose some functionality of my c++ application.

I've already embedded python and I'm able to call python code and call back c++ function for the interaction.

My problem is to be able to make the webserver run without locking the application.

Using a python thread for the webserver stop the server as soon the initialization is finished. How to give time to the python interpreter to go ahead with thread processing?

---

*old explanation*

If I create the webserver (for example with cherrypy) it's also easy to call c++ function from the browser... what's is missing it's that the c++ application is locked. My idea is to use a python thread, but from test is the python code to lock when until another python code is called (any python code).

So my conclusion is that I need to give some time to the python interpreter in during events management of the c++ application (MFC application)

*It's a best practises doing this? Is there some API function for doing this?*

Other solution is to create a c++ thread and start the interpreter using `PyThread*` functions... but my worries here is that the `GIL` lock the GUI application.

*Again: what is the best practises for this kind of job?*

Comment: Please don't ask about your solution. Describe the problem you are trying to solve instead. You haven't done a decent job doing that at all.

Comment: @IInspectable I've modified my question.... but if you say that I'm not doing a good job please also add a motivation, so I can make a better question.

Comment: You probably should have taken the [tour], when it was offered to you. Please read [ask] in particular. The update doesn't do anything to clarify the question. We cannot help you write MFC code, when you don't know MFC, C++, or the Windows API. These types of questions usually do not gather valuable help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using socket, usually you need to choose [select-vs-multi-threading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9040232/1278112).The select mode would block you app,but first make sure that's what you need.